# NXLog Forwarding to CloudWatch possible?

Tags: logging, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, nxlog, amazon-cloudwatch-events

I have found a number of items on collecting logs from CloudWatch for NXLog to then send somewhere else, but none on forwarding events to CloudWatch? It isn't really a destination, but maybe it is possible. The benfit is the SNARE format and it is already on our On-prem Windows Machines.

Anyone have any information on this or better yet - a possible Template :)

My thanks

Answer (score 0):

NXLog Enterprise Edition has already an addon letting storage of logs in AWS s3 bucket (https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide/addon-amazon-s3.html).

From there on, I assume adding a simple Lambda function (or maybe even better -SQS) to forward incoming data into CloudWatch might do the job - have you considered this way?

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks rafal.  I think that does work.  We will probably just use CloudWatch, but this could be a viable solution.  Many thanks.